# Dividing microservices in Lagom

Tags: microservices, lagom

Lagom by default creates two modules for every microservice - API and implementation.

Is it possible to divide one microservices into 3+ modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You would do this the same way you would with any other Java or Scala project: create a sub-project that is an internal library included into your service.

For an example of this look at the [Online Auction Java](https://github.com/lagom/online-auction-java) example Lagom project. Specifically, the `security` and `tools` sub-projects. These are included into other services using the `sbt` `dependsOn` method in `build.sbt`.

For example:

```
lazy val itemApi = (project in file("item-api"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      lagomJavadslApi,
      lombok
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(security, tools)
```

In this case, it is the API project that depends on the additional libraries, but you could do the same thing with your implementation project to use libraries that are not needed by the API. Note that the implementation project also depends on its corresponding API, so any dependencies of the API are inherited by the implementation.

Comment: What if I wanted to split the implementation into two parts, for example, item-impl and item-impl2? Is this possible? If yes, would it make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The person behind this idea wants to split the implementation into two parts, therefore he would like to know if it's possible to divide it in such manner.

Comment: Would the two parts run as two separate services?

Comment: No. they would run together, just the same as item-api and item-impl would.

Comment: One project would be the service, and the other would be a "library" that the other service consumes as described above. It's very similar to any Java webapp: one project would be the deployable war file and it would pull in other projects as dependencies as needed.